# silex overload class User

Tags: symfony, silex

I wish for the project need to override the class User in Silex 2.0:

```
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User;
```

I absolutely do not see how.
My ultimate goal is to overload the method:

```
final class User implements AdvancedUserInterface
{
     /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return unserialize($this->roles[0]); // work (overload)
        return $this->roles; // Not work (delete)
    }
}
```

Have you any idea how to do this?

Thank you !

Comment: And what is the problem to override this class?

Comment: Same question on [GitHub](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/issues/1436)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final class [`User`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v3.1.5/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/User.php) is only defined for the [`InMemoryUserProvider`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v3.1.5/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/InMemoryUserProvider.php).

To read this database from Silex, you have to code your own `UserProvider` and [configure it](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/providers/security.html#defining-a-custom-user-provider).

Instead of extending the `User` class, the correct value of `$roles` can be set in the constructor.

If you took the documentation example, you should replace this line:

```
return new User($user['username'], $user['password'], explode(',', $user['roles']), true, true, true, true);
```

By this:

```
return new User($user['username'], $user['password'], unserialize($user['roles']), true, true, true, true);
```

Otherwise, the best practice is to create your own User class.

```
/**
 * User is the user implementation used by the in-memory user provider.
 *
 * This should not be used for anything else.
 */
```